# PuTTY terminal behaviour differs between two accounts on same server

Tags: ssh, terminal, putty

I'm using PuTTY to connect to my server where I have two accounts.  One account gives me a colour terminal and responds correctly to the home/end keys, while the other account gives me a black-n-white prompt and the home/end keys produce `~`s.
Both accounts have the same .bashrc file, and the PuTTY settings are identical except for the username specified.

Can someome please help me understand what is causing this?

*Edit*
To fix the Home/End keys, I needed to add */etc/inputrc* and */lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.** to the available files in the jail, thnx to grawity's pointers.

To fix the colour prompt problem, using the standard *.bashrc*, I needed to add */usr/bin/tput* to the jail as well.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal behaves the same way. But the keypresses are interpreted and prompts printed not by the terminal itself, but by programs running in it – primarily the *shell*.

Your two accounts might be set up to use different login shells – one uses bash (or maybe zsh), the other is likely set to plain /bin/sh.

Use `getent passwd USERNAME` to check the configured shell for that account, and `chsh` to set it.

---

Additionally, even in bash/zsh, the prompt format and key information are read from outside files.

- The prompt, as well as aliases which enable colors for 'ls', are configured in "profile" and "bashc" files. Namely `/etc/bashrc` (or similar) and `~/.bashrc`.
- The keys are recognized by *readline*, which mainly uses the ncurses "terminfo" database `/usr/share/terminfo` but also has various custom settings in `/etc/inputrc`.

  (Zsh uses its own zshzle, I don't know what all files it needs, but I'm sure it requires the terminfo DB anyway.)

For jailed accounts, make sure all these files are available. If necessary, use strace or similar tools (truss, etc.) to see what files are loaded by the shell.

Comment: Both shells are runing bash.  However, the misbehaving account is running an earlier version : `GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)`  vs `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.   This is really strange.
The account that is working is root, and the account that isn't working is jailkitted.

Comment: Ah, yeah, one more thing then.

Comment: Thanks grawity.  I have `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `usr/share/terminfo` folder, but not `/etc/inputrc`.  I'll fix that and see how I go.

Comment: After breaking that particular jail and then fixing it, it's stil not working even though I have all the files you've mentioned grawity.  Now that I understand it has something to do with Jailkit setup, I'll conduct some further searches.  If you have any other suggestions, please feel free.  Cheers.

Comment: `jk_cp -k /home/jail /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.*`  fixed the home/end keys.
Now I just need to fix the colours.  (I've updated my question as I didn't explain the colour problem as precisely as I needed to.)

Comment: All fixed now.  I needed to also add `usr/bin/tput` to the jail to make the standard *.bashrc* file exhibit the same behaviour.